# Sorting a list of floats/double which are in String format with Comparator.comparing

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to sort a list of  float values which are available in String format  for e.g.,

```
"rate": "429.0",
"rate": "129.0",
"rate": "1129.0",...
```

If I use Comparator.comparing(Room::getRate) the list will be sorted in String order which will be incorrect. So I wrote the code below where I convert String to float and then compare.

Below code works fine for me, but it looks so ugly, is there a better alternative?

```
  stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Room::getRate, 
(s1, s2) -> (Float.parseFloat(s1) > Float.parseFloat(s2) ? 1 :-1)))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can write a dedicated Comparator class  and use it so sort .  The only difference will be you will have comparator class and  sorting logic in overriden method.

Comment: Yeah aware of that, but since it is such a general problem hoping someone might have a simpler and better solution.

Answer (score 8):

you can replace `Room::getRate` to `r -> Float.parseFloat(r.getRate())` and then it would become:

```
  sorted(Comparator.comparing(
         r -> Float.parseFloat(r.getRate),
         Comparator.naturalOrder())
```

*OR*

```
Comparator.comparingDouble(r -> Double.parseDouble(r.getRate()))
```

Comment: `Comparator.comparingDouble(r -> Float.parseFloat(r.getRate()))` is shorter and expanding `float` to `double` likely to be cheaper than boxing every `float` to `Float` before comparing. I wouldn’t even be surprised if `Comparator.comparingDouble(r -> Double.parseDouble(r.getRate()))` turns out to be faster…

Comment: This worked for me! 
Thanks, however, why do we need Comparator.naturalOrder() it works fine without that too

Comment: @Holger I thought I wrote that down :|

Comment: @abhishekgaloda you don't, yes. But use the version in the edit anyway